# Kernel compilation for minimum program execution

Tags: kernel, compiling, kernel-modules, initramfs

Compiling the Kernel requires me to configure modules. I am unsure how to configure a Kernel which only supports following things:

- Programs compiled with gcc on other machines (glibc).
- I want to run my own statically compiled libraries like gnutls, does this require anything from the cryptographic section?
- Networking support. (default in Networking section should be good)

That's all. I don't need filesystems since I only want the kernel (and programs on it) to run from the RAM. I also would like to avoid kernel modules, everything should be as monolithic as possible.

Comment: How are the programs to be loaded? From RAM? How did they get into RAM? How does the kernel know where in RAM the programs are? That's what filesystems generally are used for... I think you won't be able to run a kernel without *any* filesystem.

Comment: That's what I am asking, I'm not sure what to select. But I heard that initramfs doesn't need one.

Comment: Most modules handle not a specific kernel subsystem, but a device. So at first you need to inventory these devices and pick corresponding modules. I.e. if your system has only Intel network adapters, compile `e1000`, but exclude `r8169` etc.